# Catching unknown named parameter errors

Tags: php, error-handling, arguments, parameter-passing, php-8

Functions with missing arguments throws the `ArgumentCountError` error

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ...

Whereas unknown named parameter only throws a generic error

> Error: Unknown named parameter ...

I want to catch these only these two error and so far I have the following

```
function foo(int $bar, int $baz) {}

try {
    foo(...$arr); // $arr is always an associative array

} catch (ArgumentCountError $error) {
    // ...

} catch (Error $error) {
    if (preg_match("/^Unknown named parameter/", $e->getMessage())) {
        // ...

    } else {
        throw $error;
    }
}
```

What alternative approaches do I have? Shouldn't `Unknown named parameter` get it's own error.

Edit:

For a `UnknownNamedParameterError` usage

```
try {
    $dynamicFoo(...$args);

} catch (UnknownNamedParameterError $error) {
    // if needed, a check to confirm the error happened in foo
    if (($error->getTrace()[0]["function"] ?? null) === $dynamicFoo) {
        // Hacky but whatever

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the $arr for emptiness.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't Unknown named parameter get it's own error.

Maybe, but someone needs to articulate a reason why it would be a good idea first.

Using exceptions for flow of control are one of those things that don't sound that bad, but turn out to have quite nasty suprises for people trying to maintain software.

Consider this code where there is an ArgumentCountError when a function is called by named parameters:

```
function foo($param1, $param2) 
{
   $values = [
       'param1' => $param1,
       'param2' => $param2,
       'param3' => 'john'
   ];

   bar(...$values);
}

function bar($param1, $param2, $param3) {...}


try {
    foo(...$userInput);
}
catch (ArgumentCountError $ace) {
   // tell the user they have sent the wrong parameters.
}
```

So far so good. Now imagine the signature of the function bar is changed to be:

```
function bar($param1, $param2, $surprise) {...}
```

But we forget to make the appropriate change where bar() is called in function foo. The code would fail for all users, and they would be given a misleading error message, which is pretty surprising behaviour.

Or to put it simply, catching exceptions caused by incorrect named params isn't a safe thing to do, and so PHP core doesn't pretend that it is.

> What alternative approaches do I have?

You should validate data before trying to use it, rather than trying to catch exceptions to handle bad data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there should be a custom exception for this. Anyway, regarding your solution I can't think of any alternatives right now. However, there're situations in named parameters when PHP throws `ArgumentCountError`.

- Required parameter not passed

  https://3v4l.org/laW5N
- Some internal  variadic functions don't support extra named args

  https://3v4l.org/Cjfn1